# Node.js, Hbase: Failed to connect to zookeeper

Tags: node.js, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

Using [`hbase-rpc-client`](https://github.com/falsecz/hbase-rpc-client) and trying to connect to Zookeper, I get the following error:

> Failed to connect to zookeeper. zkHosts: [my_host_name:2181] zkRoot: '/hbase'

I do know that host and port are correct, as I can see it in */master-status* under the *Software Attributes* section:

- Zookeeper Quorum: my_host_name:2181
- Zookeeper Base Path: /hbase

Furthermore, I use exactly the same configuration for ZooKeeper hostname:port to connect to my Hbase with HareDBClient, and it works.

Results of `nmap myhostname -p 2181`:

- PORT: 2181/tcp
- STATE: open
- SERVICE: unknown

Versions:

- Hadoop: 2.7.3
- Hbase: 1.3
- Node.js: 6.9.1
- hbase-rpc-client: 0.1.10

I do realize that `hbase-rpc-client`'s last supported version of hbase is 1.2.x. 
Can anybody confirm that it is not possible to use the package with hbase 1.3, and if so, recommend some up-to-date tool to connect node.js to hbase? As nothing closer to 1.3 than 1.2.x showed up during research.

Or am I just missing something in my configuration?

Comment: any more error context?

Comment: That's it, unfortunatelly. Error method in the package is not based on actual connection, as far as I can say looking into `node_modules/hbase-rpc-client/lib/client.js`. However there are too many dependencies to be 100% sure about that, so I didn't include this in my question. So short answer is: no, there is no more error context, this is the full message I get. Do you happen to use the package and maybe there is something I could try based on your experience with it?

Comment: Did you ever try connecting via zkCli.sh to test the connection via the standard zk connection string with the '/hbase' tacked onto the end?